# Send email from fake account

Tags: java, email, smtp

Is there a way to send an email from any account (real or fake) in Java? I need to do that for one of my projects where the user has full knowledge of the emails expected.

If that's not feasible, is there any other way to send an email to a valid recipient without prompting the user to create a mail account, to sign up, or to use my own mail account as a sender for all users?

Comment: Yes, SMTP doesn't provide email verification methods to verify email address.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but you need a smtp server (like sendmail). You can install a smtp server in your machine & send mail using that server. But for security reasons popular mail services like hotmail, gmail does not allow smtp server with dynamic ip addresse to send mail to their servers. You need static ip address & of course ip address should not be in any spam database. In case of yahoo they check if your ip address is in any spam database. If you use static ip address you can be easily traced.

Comment: This isn't actually an answer to the question asked. Answers on Stack Overflow are expected to be *directly* related to the question that is being asked.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are probably looking for a SMTP client.

Here is an example of how to implement it:
http://www.roseindia.net/javamail/SMTPClient.shtml

The challenge is probably to find a SMTP server that accepts your mails and doesnt filter them out as spam.

Comment: So does the host need to be a valid one?

Comment: Depends on how the SMTP server is configured. But you will probably have a hard time finding one that accepts anything.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about java, but you can send mails from any mail id using php mail. There are many free web hosting sites which provide smtp server access and php.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose whatever "from" field you like.  You can simply set it using the JavaMail API.  The only possible restriction is that you need to ensure that the SMTP server you're connecting to accepts the message - and that no other system in the line rejects it as Spam, etc.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#setFrom() for details.

Comment: Oh ok. The JavaMail API takes the username and password of the sender though. I am guessing those need to be valid ones right?

Comment: With the API link I provided, this sets the "From" address on the "envelop".  The username/password used to connect to the SMTP server are entirely separate - though in many (proper) cases, the username may be the same.

Comment: Broken link! Please fix it if possible! :)